# Cant change textfield in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am writing a javascript program which is supposed to change the text of a textfield once submit button is clicked

```
<script>

function change()
{
    document.getElementById("set").value="helloworld";
}

</script>
```

the textfield and submit button:

```
<form>
Enter Text <input type="text" id="set" >
<input type="submit" value="Press here" onclick="change()" />
</form>
```

once I press submit it only displays an empty textfield. But when I remove 'form' it displays the correct result. Can anyone explain why ?

On a similar note can anyone explain why  'form' is important when we can collect data without it as well..

Thanks in advance...

Comment: it's pretty basic. you  submit a pate so the page get refresh

Answer (score 3):

On click of the `submit` button, form is being submitted and hence page is unloaded.

Prevent form submission.

```js
function change(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  
  document.getElementById("set").value = "helloworld";
}
```

```html
<form>
  Enter Text <input type="text" id="set">
  <input type="submit" value="Press here" onclick="change(event)" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change input type submit to button and then try.